# "Application defined or object defined error" occurs only when triggering macro via customUI (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

When using a cutomUI in an excel workbook that looks like that:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"> 
    <ribbon >
        <tabs>          
            <tab id="tab1" label="tab" visible ="true" tag ="tab1" >            
                <group id="sGroup" autoScale="true" centerVertically="true" label="bla" visible ="true" tag ="grp" >                
                    <button id="closeButton" size="large" label="close" imageMso="BroadcastEnd" tag ="close" onAction="closeCustom" 
                            visible="true" enabled="true"/>
                            
                </group>                
            </tab>          
        </tabs>     
    </ribbon>   
</customUI>
```

and the corresponding Callback

```
Public Sub closeCustom(control As IRibbonControl)
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

I get the "Application defined or object defined error" (without 1004) when:

- clicking the customUI close button AND
- 1 or more additional workbooks are open AND
- the next workbook, that will become the ActiveWorkbook after closing ThisWorkbook, has the Workbook_Activate event

If I for example call the function via the immediate window "closeCustom nothing", no error will occur.

Just if you wonder, the original workbook and customUI have much more functionality. I was only able to get to this point of abstraction/simplification, but found no solution other than setting `application.enableevents = false`. But then the user has to turn it on manually.

I would appreciate any help for this problem (getting rid of the error).

### How to reproduce the error:

- Create two workbooks with macros: book1.xlsm, book2.xlsm
- rename book1.xlsm to book1.zip
- Open book1.zip and add the Folder CustomUI
- Add the file customUI.xml to the folder CustomUI
- add the xml/text I posted first to customUI.xml
- Change the _rels/.rels file so that it contains:
- 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="xl/workbook.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="CustomUI/customUI.xml"/>
</Relationships>
```

- rename book1.zip to book1.xlsm
- open book1.xlsm
- in the vba editor add a new module
- add folowing code to the new module
- 

```
Sub closeCustom(control As IRibbonControl)
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

- open book2.xlsm
- in the vba editor go to ThisWorkbook
- paste following code
- 

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Debug.Print "a"
End Sub
```

- save all
- now both workbooks are open (only those two)
- click on the tab called "tab" in the ribbon
- click on the close button in the ribbon tab "tab"
- book1.xlsm closes and Error pops up

Comment: Do you want using that button after closing `ThisWorkbook`? The custom Tab and button in discussion have a meaning **only if the workbook creating them is open**. Is it anything I am missing?

Comment: No. the workbook shall close and with it the button in the customUI ;) Maybe you wonder why there is a custom close button. This is legacy code and if I have to change it, I need to basically rewrite all the code. And the code is not maintainable at all. This would kill a lot of time.

Comment: There must be other code at play, I am unable to repro. What code is in that activate event?

Comment: Do you get an error with a "debug" button?  If not, try changing your error handling to "Break in class module" and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @jkpieterse I added a how to reproduce the error section. The activate event just has debug.print "a" for testing purpose in it.

Comment: @TimWilliams What shall the debug button do? I don't understand what you want me to do.

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to reproduce the issue.